# Specify linker folder which including space in the name

Tags: c, eclipse, linker, space

I'm trying to create an application for Linux using Eclipse.
It needs external .so file and I included it to Libraries.
(Project Property >> C/C++ Build >> Settings >> Tool Settings >> Cross GCC Linker >> Libraries)

I can compile the application but there is an error...
Looking Console log, it said that

```
22:38:05 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project My ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
x86_64-nxxxt-linux-gcc "-LC:\\Program" "Files\\Nxxxxx" "xxxxxx\\Rx"     "Images\\NxxxxT\\Linux-x64" -o My My.o -lxxxxxt 
x86_64-nxxxt-linux-gcc: error: Files\Nxxxxx: No such file or directory
x86_64-nxxxt-linux-gcc: error: xxxxxx\Rx: No such file or directory
x86_64-nxxxt-linux-gcc: error: Images\NxxxxT\Linux-x64: No such file or directory
22:38:05 Build Finished (took 81ms)
```

(I exchange some alphabets to "x")

It seems that the error is caused by space which is included in folder name.
I think it is ordinary case in Linux environment.
I enclosed the path in quotation marks like this.
"C:\Program Files\Nxxxxx xxxxxx\Rx Images\NxxxxT\Linux-x64"
But compiler said that

c:/program files/Nxxxxx xxxxxx/eclipse/...../4.7.2/ld.exe: cannot find -lxxxxxt

I couldn't understand what was happening, but next I copied the folder which included lxxxxxt.so file to "C:\Linux_x64".
I tried it and with "", but compiler said

c:/program files/Nxxxxx xxxxxx/eclipse/...../4.7.2/ld.exe: cannot find -lxxxxxt

Ummmmm....... I have no idea to resolve this problem.

Does anyone has any good idea?

Comment: Instead of using `"C:\Program Files\Nxxxxx xxxxxx\Rx Images\NxxxxT\Linux-x64"` try `"C:/Program Files/Nxxxxx xxxxxx/Rx Images/NxxxxT/Linux-x64"`.

Comment: place double quotes around the complete path and to make things simpler in the future, do not make directory names that contain spaces.

Comment: Dear all, thank you so much for your kind help.
I edited the path "C:/Program Files/Nxxxxx xxxxxx/Rx Images/NxxxxT/Linux-x64" but the result was same...

I will investigate more by myself. If you have any further idea, please let me know.

Thank you!